# Intellij Idea on OpenSuse Linux

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, opensuse

I am getting following error after downloading and extracting Intellij Idea on OpenSuse Linux 42.1 (Latest 32 bit OS), I have installed JDK 7 and `JAVA_HOME`/`PATH` environment variables are setup correctly.

Command:

```
~/Work/idea-IC-145.1617.8/bin> ./idea.sh
```

Error:

> /idea-IC-145.1617.8/bin/idea.sh: line 197:  4049 Bus error
>   (core dumped) LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$IDE_BIN_HOME:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
>   "$JAVA_BIN" $AGENT "-Xbootclasspath/a:$IDE_HOME/lib/boot.jar"
>   -classpath "$CLASSPATH" $VM_OPTIONS "-Djb.vmOptionsFile=$VM_OPTIONS_FILE"
>   "-XX:ErrorFile=$HOME/java_error_in_IDEA_%p.log"
>   "-XX:HeapDumpPath=$HOME/java_error_in_IDEA.hprof" -Djb.restart.code=88
>   -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2016.1 $IDE_PROPERTIES_PROPERTY -Didea.jre.check=true com.intellij.idea.Main "$@"

I am not sure what is wrong here, as this does not explains what is the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format the code samples so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide any additional detial that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: Are you using OpenJDK or the Oracle one?

Comment: I am using Oracle JDK v 1.7

Comment: OK, I've just climbed out of a week-long battle with getting multiple versions of the JDK installed on my machine, and after looking at the function that contains line 197 in `idea.sh`, I'm inclined to ask if your JDK has `tools.jar` and `rt.jar` in its `lib` directory?

Comment: It just occurred to me that I had to create a hack to make Maven and IntelliJ play nice together. I set an alias in my `.zshrc` that changes the `$JAVA_HOME` variable temporarily: `idea='JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/java8" && /usr/local/bin/idea'`. Perhaps update your JDK to 1.8 and try again?

Comment: Need to be careful about the correct architecture is used like 32 bit version for 32 bit OS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Reinstalling the IDEA 32bit version resolved the issue. Here are the versions userd: OS 64 Bit, JDK 32 bit, IDEA 32 bit.